# HackerRank - Matrix Rotation

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, comparative-review, time-limit-exceeded, matrix

[Problem statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matrix-rotation-algo)

> Given a matrix (up to 300 × 300), rotate each element *R* steps anti-clockwise along concentric rectangular paths (*R* up to 10<sup>9</sup>).

The algorithm is rated as hard on HackerRank.

On April, 2016, I wrote the algorithm with a bug,  scored 8 out of maximum 80 points. I could not find the bug after hours work.

On Dec. 6, 2016, I reviewed the code again, and then decided to use meaningful variable names, removed all abstract variables names, and found the bug because of reusing the function `RotateAntiClockwiseByLayer` input argument `steps`,

`steps = steps % circleLength;`

Bug fix is to declare a new variable: `actualSteps`, so the statement is

`int actualSteps = steps % circleLength;`

and scored 80. Lesson learned: **Meaningful variable names are helpful to do static analysis, code review, and bug fixes.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RotateArray
{
class Program
{
    /*
     * Int16 maximum value is 32676, less than 4 * 10^9
     */
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MatrixRotation();             
    }       

    private static void MatrixRotation()
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] arr = input.Split(' ');
        int row = Convert.ToInt32(arr[0].Trim());
        int col = Convert.ToInt32(arr[1].Trim());
        int rotations = Convert.ToInt32(arr[2].Trim());

        int[,] matrix = new int[row, col];
        int[][] mx = new int[row][];

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            mx[i] = GetInts(Console.ReadLine(), col);

            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                matrix[i, j] = mx[i][j];
        }

        RotateAntiClockwiseByLayer(matrix, rotations);

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            string s = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                s += matrix[i, j] + " ";
            Console.WriteLine(s.Trim());
        }
    }

    static int[] GetInts(string inp, int cnt)
    {
        string[] vals = inp.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        int[] res = new int[cnt];
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            res[i] = Convert.ToInt32(vals[i]);
        }
        return res;
    }

    /*
     * Dec. 6, 2016
     * Review the code, 
     * follow the code style - 
     * 1. Do not use abstract variable name 
     * 
     * 
     */
    public static bool RotateAntiClockwiseByLayer(int[,] matrix, int steps)
    {
        if (matrix == null) return false;

        int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);  // row
        int cols = matrix.GetLength(1);  // column 

        int startRow = 0;
        int startCol = 0;           

        while (rows > 1 && cols > 1)
        {
            int circleLength = 2 * rows + 2 * cols - 4;
            int actualSteps = steps % circleLength;

            for (int step = 0; step < actualSteps; step++) //  move one step anti-clockwise a time
            {
                int lt_corner = matrix[startRow, startCol]; // left-top corner element

                for (int colIndex = startCol; colIndex < startCol + cols - 1; colIndex++)
                    matrix[startRow, colIndex] = matrix[startRow, colIndex + 1];

                int lastCol = startCol + cols - 1;
                for (int rowIndex = startRow; rowIndex < startRow + rows - 1; rowIndex++)
                    matrix[rowIndex, lastCol] = matrix[rowIndex + 1, lastCol];


                int lastRow = startRow + rows - 1;
                for (int colIndex = startCol + cols - 1; colIndex >= startCol + 1; colIndex--)
                    matrix[lastRow, colIndex] = matrix[lastRow, colIndex - 1];

                for (int rowIndex = startRow + rows - 1; rowIndex >= 1 + startRow; rowIndex--)
                    matrix[rowIndex, startCol] = matrix[rowIndex - 1, startCol];

                matrix[startRow + 1, startCol] = lt_corner;
            }

            startRow++;
            startCol++;

            rows -= 2;
            cols -= 2;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Also, I read a lot of submissions, in C/C++/ Java/ JavaScript. For example, [one solution](http://juliachencoding.blogspot.ca/2016/12/matrix-rotation-code-review-series-3-of.html) is to declare a global jagged array with size 300, using 300 MB of space.

There are several concerns about the code I wrote. Inside the function `RotateAntiClockwiseByLayer`, there are four `for` loop inside a `while` loop, inside the first `for` loop:

```
for (int step = 0; step < actualSteps; step++)
```

+1 four times, -1 four times. It's easy to make a mistake in 8 places. And I saw an idea to replace 4 `for` loops, using one `for` loop instead with 4 `if` statements. The code looks simple, no -1, +1 compared to my solution:

```
int parameter = (maxRow + maxCol) * 2 - min * 4;

int row = r;
int col = c;
for (int a = 0; a < rot%parameter; a++) {
    if (col == min && row < maxRow) {
        row++;
    }
    else if (row == maxRow && col < maxCol) {
        col++;
    }
    else if (row > min && col == maxCol) {
        row--;
    }
    else if (row == min && col > min) {
        col--;
    }
}
result[row][col] = arr[r][c];
```

I talked about my practice, concerns, seek better ideas to solve the problem.

Comment: A 300x300 array of 4 byte values is 360000 bytes, which is 360 KB not 360 MB.  So you can use a temp matrix without worrying about exceeding the 512 MB limit.

Comment: @JS1, you are correct on the calculation - 360KB, not 360MB.

Comment: Good work! Now the version with new variable names is much much easier to understand so I guess I can take a look at it. The first one was like _WTF_ is this? ;-D As there aren't any reviews yet, you can replace the orginal code with the new one. Two versions just confuse.

Comment: @t3chb0t, I am removing the first version of code to follow your advice.